# What could be the reasons for [GAPPS] 'Script experienced an error'?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google apps script JS function, which was executing and doing its job just fine. All of a sudden, an error started appearing: 'Script *sendReply* experienced an error'. When I try to open the *Details*, no info appears, just the same message with no actual details. The related Stackdriver logs appear only 10-15 minutes after execution, with *Unknown* outcome status.

The function itself continues working normally, successfully executing some HTTP requests with UrlFetchApp (if that matters). I'm really struggling to look for a root for that pop-up, as no changes to the script itself were made lately.

```
function sendReply() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ss.toast('Sending letters...');
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
var commentType = getCommentType(sheetName);
var startRow = 3;
var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var numCols = sheet.getLastColumn();
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(3, 1, lastRow - 2, numCols);
var data = dataRange.getValues();
var numSent = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var ticketId = row[0];
    var body = row[2];
    var status = row[6];
    if (status == "Done" && body !="") {
      createComment(ticketId, body, commentType);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 7).setValue("Sent"); 
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 9).setValue(new Date());
      numSent++;
    }
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  if (numSent > 0) {
    ss.toast('Sent ' + numSent + ' new letters.')
  } else {
    ss.toast('No letters sent.')
  }
  dataRange.sort({column: 7, ascending: false});
}
```

Comment: I've been seeing this error a lot also.  Personally, I can't explain it because the code has been running fine for quite a while.  I suspect it's something on Googles side.  The worse thing about it is that the error message is virtually useless and provide no debugging information at all.  So if your not really familiar with debugging and app your basilcly screwed.  In my case the app is generating a dialog and it seems to be associated with the dialog but so far I haven't found the magical answer.

Comment: You say you have a JS function - does it mean that you have a function on the client side, in th html part of your Apps Script project? Please give more details and explain how you call the function and under what circumstances the error appears. Does it occur only sporadiously or every time?

Comment: @ziganotschka once a new line of the sheet is ready, a person executes the function via an addon, made with SpreadsheetApp.getUI, and further adding. In the code, you can see a function called createComment. It has some parameters that fulfill the JSON payload, making a further POST request. Once a person presses on the addon button, the script starts running, makes its job and the error appears right after. The fun fact is, that it no longer pops up today. Happens at random, I'd say

Comment: @Cooper: Since you are talking about debugging, does it mean that the error is caused by a bug in the code? Or would you rather suggest it is an issue from Google's side?

Comment: @RomanHladkyy: Does the error only happen for the Add-on or also for bound scripts calling `SpreadsheetApp.getUI`?  Does the error appear before the `toast`message and if not - at what point?

Comment: @ziganotschka I always assumed it could be my error but in this case I haven't been able to find anything and the error occurs intermittently.  Like today it hasn't happen at all.

Comment: I experienced yesterday a similar issue even without an Add-on - just with a custom menu. I filed a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/2/issues/174678820) aboutit - feel free to comment and provide more details that might help reproducing / tracking it down.

Comment: @ziganotschka it was appearing both using the add-on call and executing the function itself. Toast message was appearing before the error, which was popping up at the very end of execution. Btw, thanks for filing the bug!

Comment: How are you calling `sendReply()`? From client side with `google.script.run`?